# Schengen Greece Visa/passport withdrawal process

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, greece

My schengen visa is being consulted however I need to withdraw the passport as I have a scheduled travel.
What is the process of Passport withdrawal and how many days does it take?

Comment: Did you apply via VFS Global? If you wish to withdraw your application you are usually required to visit the application centre and submit your withdrawal request. VFS may not be able to provide you any definite timelines to get your passport back but you can check the status of your passport on their website. Fees are not usually refundable.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases the application is done locally. So you will have to contact them directly and ask when you can come by and pick up the passport, thus withdrawing you application.

Often the local consulate (which you have not supplied) web site will contain information on how to deal with the matter that the passport is needed during application. This is, however, the exception to the rule and not always possible.